# Centos 8 - ping 8.8.8.8 (connect: Network is unreachable)

Tags: networking, centos, centos-8

I have set up a CentOS VM and I'm trying to bridge the network, but it's not working. I've spent more than 3 hours trying solutions I found on the internet, but I couldn't make it work because I lack experience in this area. 
Here is some information:

```
root@desktop internet]# ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable


[root@desktop internet]# ip route
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 


[root@desktop internet]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160 
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=eui64
NAME=ens160
UUID=d6564f1e-0165-4ffa-abb7-6f85d368f587
DEVICE=ens160
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=143.248.152.195
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=143.248.152.1

[root@desktop internet]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160 
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=eui64
NAME=ens160
UUID=d6564f1e-0165-4ffa-abb7-6f85d368f587
DEVICE=ens160
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=143.248.152.195
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=143.248.152.1


[root@desktop internet]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
# Created by anaconda

[root@desktop internet]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```